# Размер макета под все экраны

Tags: android

Вопрос уже 100 раз обговаривался,но никак не могу разобраться в нем окончательно.

По сему, прошу знающих подсказать и объяснить моменты.

Мне нужно сделать приложение для смартфонов и планшетов.

Дизайнер задал вопросы:

**1. Какое разрешение макета рисовать ?

 2. С какого разрешения до какого
        двигаться ?**

Как ответить на эти вопрос ?

Ссылки на доку Screen Sizes знаю, но не помогли..

Answer (score 1):

Средства Android позволяют из одной картинки сделать картинки под все разрешения, поэтому напрашивается ответ, что самого максимального, но вообще можно ограничиться Full HD и из него по средствам ImageAsset, также можно использовать VectorAsset, но это уже для минимум 21 версии андрюхи, а векторное изображение насколько мне известно подгоняется и масштабируется под все экраны само и без всяких проблем, что экономит ресурсы. В любом случае в интернете есть ресурсы, которые позволяют сразу нарезать из картинки нужные под нужные разрешения, а также [есть плагин](http://www.cutandslice.me) для фотошопа, который делает тоже самое

Comment: "самого максимального" это какого?)

Comment: Я же написал, что Full HD можно ограничится и нарезать его потом под все остальные спец. плагинами или ресурсами

Comment: @researcher Вы поймите, что тут не дело даже в разрешении, всё равно ресурсы или плагин нарежут нужное, просто чем больше изначальное разрешение, тем лучше оно будет выглядеть даже в мелких разрешениях

Comment: т.е. говорить дизайнеру, чтобы макет рисовала с разрешением 1920×1080? А потом все кнопки-фоны и тд дизайнер нарежит на более мелкие, да ?

Comment: Full HD какое-то почти квадратное выходит..

Comment: @researcher Ещё раз говорю, не главное конкретное разрешение, пусть отношение сторон (пропорции) будут сохранены, но главное разрешение изначальное побольше брать

Answer (score -1):

Минимальная ширина 360px, максимальная Full HD 1920px. До 2K-4K мониторов еще мало кто дорос.

Использовать стиль display:inline-block для каждого блока так, чтобы при сжатии экрана блоки становились друг под друга, пользоваться комбинацией max-width:..px и width:100%; height иногда можно ставить в auto.

Для изображений лучше использовать width или height в значении auto, либо оформлять картинки как div с background:url(../url.jpg) no-repeat center center / cover; При таком оформлении происходит обрезка не вмещающихся краев либо по высоте, либо по ширине, но часто это не важно.

Можно использовать media queries, например
 
или
@media (min-width: 1024px) {}

И на мой взгляд достаточно 3-х вариантов: 360px для вертикальных мобильников, 1024px для планшетов и основного css.

Comment: спасибо за отклик. Но по моему Вы немного не о том.. Вы про ВЕБ-дизайн ?

Comment: Извините, если не то